# how to extract camera info and images from ros bag?

Tags: camera, ros, bag

I have a ros bag and its information as following

```
path:        zed.bag

version:     2.0

duration:    3:55s (235s)

start:       Nov 12 2014 04:28:20.90 (1415737700.90)

end:         Nov 12 2014 04:32:16.65 (1415737936.65)

size:        668.3 MB

messages:    54083

compression: none [848/848 chunks]

types:       sensor_msgs/CameraInfo      [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
             sensor_msgs/CompressedImage [8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]
             tf2_msgs/TFMessage          [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]

topics:      /stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle              3741 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo  
             /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle/compressed     3753 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle             3741 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo 
             /stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle/compressed    3745 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /tf                                                  39103 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage          (2 connections)
```

I can extract images by following
 http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data
but issue occurs when I want to get camera info, Do anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

One can solve it via echoing the text-based information into a file using [rostopic](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic):

```
rostopic echo -b zed.bag /stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle > data.txt
```